# htaccess rewrite multiple folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hello here is my htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#REWRITE QUERY STRINGS!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*).php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*).html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*).js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*).css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*).png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*).bmp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*).jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*).gif
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ar
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?do=$1 [QSA]
```

now what this does is when I want to access : `domain.com/home` is like accessing `domain.com/index.php?do=home` which is great , but when I try to access french language for example : `domain.com/fr/home` it doesn't work but `domain.com/fr/index.php?do=home` works do you have any idea I can achieve this for tr language, arabic and english also.Thanks
**PS: index.php file is located in fr , tr , ar and en folders**

Comment: If you want /fr/home to be rewritten, then why "%{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr" ?

Comment: because I think htaccess is in the root path so it will be added to it not to the fr folder

Comment: But it means no rewrite when the uri starts with "/fr" !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the folwoing code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|html|js|css|png|bmp|jpg|gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(m|ar|fr|tr|en)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$     /index.php?do=$1 [QSA,L]

#three lines above summarize your original code and exclude all request 
# for m,ar,fr,tr,en with / , it means when request to any directory 
# of them

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(m|ar|fr|tr|en)/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(m|ar|fr|tr|en)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$    $1/index.php?do=$2 [QSA,L]

# the three lines above will match any request passes the first rule 
# and starts with any of your chosen directories and prevent any loop
```

If you want to exclude the same files extensions from the second rule you could add this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|html|js|css|png|bmp|jpg|gif)$` to it as well

Comment: yes it's working thanks , but still when I want to access domain.com/fr it redirects me to domain.com/fr/?do=fr

Comment: ya because it should be domain.com/fr/ with slash , i mentioned that , but if you need to get without slash i could modify it

Comment: add this line for first rule and test it again RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(m|ar|fr|tr|en)$

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to introduce a more general rewriting rule prior to your rule for the default language:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/(.*)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&do=$2 [END,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /index.php?do=$1 [END,QSA]
```

You may need to add some exceptions in form of `RewriteCond`s or even switch to an explicit naming of possible language keys instead of the `([a-z]{2})`...

If you experience an http status 500 ("internal server error") due to the `END` flag then chances are that you are using a very old version of the apache http server and need to use the `L` flag instead. Should work the same for this case.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).